# Errors installation on USB

Tags: usb, install

i am trying to install Elementary OS on a usb stick and i'm having several problems:

1 - First of all, the installation process takes several hours to complete (around 6-7 hours). I don't think is a matter of the USB stick because i have a 3.0 Kingston Data Traveler stick, which should be good enough for a good writing performance

2 - Even if the installation ends with success, elementary stucks on the splash screen after the boot

I am using a Dell Inspiron 5370 with 8GB Ram, Windows OS version is 1903.

I am newbie in the Linux world, so i don't know if i gave sufficient informations.

Thanks for help :)